# mysql failed connection statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, php-8

I'm trying to check the connection with MySQL databse using the following code:

```
<?php
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','ts');


$link = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);

    if($link === false){
      header('Location: dberror.php');
    }else {
      echo "connected successfully";
    }

?>
```

When I try to give incorrect information to test the statement if the connection is not established like giving an incorrect database name, the header is not working and shows the following error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'ts' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tst\dbcon.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tst\dbcon.php(8): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ts') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tst\dbcon.php on line 8**

But when the connection is established the else statement is working.

So please how to make a user redirection if the connection failed?

Comment: You could choose to  *catch and handle* the exception. That's as good as way of dealing with errors as the one you showed us, and it's the default configuration going forward.

Comment: Not related to your question but 1. Please don't use `root` for web application. 2. Give the root user a password.

Comment: Use mysqli_connect_error() to fetch the error.

Comment: Reading the error message, especially "Unknown database 'ts'", what do you think is the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Return values for `mysqli_connect()` are an **object** or **false**. It only returns **false** if the connection fails. Try var_dump the result of `mysqli_connect()` to see if you're getting an **object**. Remember the database field is optional because it can be selected later using `mysqli_select_db()`, so even if that's empty you will still get an **object**.

Once the connection is made you can see errors using `mysqli_error()`.